# Create trigger that after insert updates

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have a profile table with bal_load int column.
I have 2 more tables namely debt and payment both with amount column.
I need to make a trigger of after inserting a value to debt would add profile.bal_load's current value with the inserted debt.amount while subtract if the insert is coming from payment.

PROFILE's table

```
+--+--------+
|ID|BAL_LOAD|
+--+--------+
|1 |500     |
|2 |300     |
+--+--------+
```

If an insert like this would happen at debt's table,

DEBT

```
+--+----------+------+
|ID|PROFILE_ID|AMOUNT|
+--+----------+------+
|1 |1         |20    |
+--+----------+------+
```

then the trigger should add bal_load with debt's amount.

PROFILE

```
+--+--------+
|ID|BAL_LOAD|
+--+--------+
|1 |520     | -->500+20
|2 |300     |
+--+--------+
```

If an insert like this would happen at payment's table,

PAYMENT

```
+--+----------+------+
|ID|PROFILE_ID|AMOUNT|
+--+----------+------+
|1 |2         |220   |
+--+----------+------+
```

then the trigger should subtract bal_load with payment's amount.

PROFILE

```
+--+--------+
|ID|BAL_LOAD|
+--+--------+
|1 |520     |
|2 |80      | -->300-220
+--+--------+
```

This is my haggard trigger for insert of debt's amount

```
create trigger bal_load_debt after insert on debt
for each row
begin
update profile
set bal_load = bal_load + amount
where profile.id = debt.profile_id;
end
```

and for insert of payment's amount

```
create trigger bal_load_payment after insert on payment
for each row
begin
update profile
set bal_load = bal_load + amount
where profile.id = payment.profile_id;
end
```

Please help :)

For update, I used this

```
CREATE TRIGGER bal_load_debt
AFTER INSERT
ON debt
FOR EACH ROW
     UPDATE Profile
     SET bal_load = bal_load + NEW.amount
     WHERE profile.id = debt.profile_id
```

I got this error message

> 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `for each row` option

Comment: I'm sorry to make a confusion, I'm using xampp's mysql. Btw thank you for your response :)

Comment: The following example may help: [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65cda/1).

Comment: I've checked the example and I think it works well.I tried making a new database and put the triggers you have here. But there's always this problem with the trigger creation at WHERE `profile`.`id` = NEW.`profile_id` saying "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6" @wchiquito

Comment: Wait, I tried using xampp's UI. I guess the inline execution of creating the trigger made the trouble. It worked! Thank you very much!! :) @wchiquito

Answer (score 2):

Your triggers are wrong at several points:

1. SQL Server doesn't have an `for each row` option
2. You need to define what **table** this trigger is on
3. The trigger will fire once for the statement, but that statement *could* insert (or update) multiple rows, and you need to deal with that

So your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bal_load_debt 
ON dbo.Debt
AFTER INSERT 
AS
     UPDATE dbo.Profile
     SET bal_load = bal_load + SUM(i.amount)
     FROM Inserted i    -- newly inserted rows 
     WHERE Profile.id = i.profile_id;
```

The newly inserted rows (which *can be* multiple!) are available in the `Inserted` pseudo table (which has the exact same structure as the table the trigger is attached to) - you can grab information about those rows from that table in your trigger.

In the case of an `UPDATE`, the `Deleted` pseudo table will contain the *old values* (before the `UPDATE`), while the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain the *new values* (after the `UPDATE`) - so you have both sets of values available in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

Read **all the details** of the various options in the `CREATE TRIGGER` command [in the freely available MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) which should **always** be your first place to go look for SQL Server specific help